# SQL: Left joining optional column should show in the table but with different row

Tags: sql, sqlite

Imagine an application form with different sections: A, B, C and D.
B should be based on A.
C should be based on B, but is optional.
Can proceed to D even if C is null but applicant will have less options in the future -- so this will be related to B and C.

A day after, the applicant will edit Form C. This data should not be attached to the existing D since the options are now different.

So there are now 2 scenarios/applications:

1. Applicant has Section D with no Section C
2. Applicant has Section C related to B, but should proceed with different Section D.

Here are my pseudo tables. I want to join them and should show the optional scenario.

```
[Table A]
id    date
1     07-11-2021

[Table B]
id    date         A_id
1     07-11-2021   1

[Table C]
id    date         B_id 
1     07-12-2021   1

[Table D]
id    date         B_id    C_id (optional)
1     07-11-2021   1       null
```

I would like to get the following table

```
[Forms table]
A_id    B_id    C_id    D_id 
1       1       null    1
1       1       1       null
```

Here is what I tried

```
SELECT 
    A.ID as A_id,
    B.ID as B_id,
    C.ID as C_id,
    D.ID as D_id
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_id = A.ID
LEFT JOIN C ON C.B_id = B.ID
LEFT JOIN D ON D.B_id = B.ID
```

But the result has only 1 row

```
[Forms table]
A_id    B_id    C_id    D_id 
1       1       1       1
```

How can I separate the 2 scenarios?

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Please, add the one back that you are actually using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is to add a condition to your `ON` clause for table `D`:

```
LEFT JOIN D ON D.B_id = B.ID AND C.ID IS NULL
```

If you want two null rows in case you don't find neither C nor D, use `UNION ALL` instead:

```
SELECT A.ID as A_id, B.ID as B_id, C.ID as C_id, NULL as D_id
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_id = A.ID
LEFT JOIN C ON C.B_id = B.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ID as A_id, B.ID as B_id, NULL as C_id, D.ID as D_id
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_id = A.ID
LEFT JOIN D ON D.B_id = B.ID
```